# Pass php variable to html input type tag in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

In PHP, I need to pass a variable to a html input type tag. How can I pass this?

I have tried to pass the html tag id, but nothing is happening.

Here my `mysql code`:

```
include('db_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $skills = $_POST["skills"];
}
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $skills = $_POST["skills"];
    //print_r($skills);die;
}
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE `name` ='$skills'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    $project[] = $row;
}
foreach ($project as $value) {
    $pg_address = $value['pg_address'];
    $pg_type = $value['pg_type'];
    $pg_owner = $value['pg_incharge_name'];
    $pg_mobile = $value['pg_incharge_mobile'];
    //print_r($pg_mobile);die;
}
```

Here my `html code`:

```
<div class="search">
    <label>PG Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="pgname" placeholder="Search by PG Name" name="pgname" list="locations" class="searchlocation" />  
    <button type="submit1" id ="submit1" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search searchButtonSearch"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#pgname" ).autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.php"
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name= "address" value="<?php echo $value['pg_address']; ?>" required/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
    <label>PG Owner Name</label>
    <input class="border" type="text" name= "pg_owner" value="<?php echo $value['pg_owner ']; ?> required />
</div>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: 1. You only define `$skills` if there's a post request, but you always try to use that variable, regardless. 2. You're overwriting the `$pg_*` variables on each iteration (they will only contain the last row after the loop). 3. How are the PHP code and the HTML related? Are they in the same file?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Do you have display errors turned on? Checked the error log?

Comment: same file only this

Comment: Are your mysql and html code in the same file?

Comment: same file only sir.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<?php

include('db_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $skills = $_POST["skills"];
}

$sql ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$skills%'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    $project[] = $row;
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="search">
    <label>PG Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="skills" placeholder="Search by PG Name" name="skills" list="locations" class="searchlocation" />  
    <button type="submit1" id ="submit1" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search searchButtonSearch">Search</i>
    </button>
</div>
</form>

<?php

foreach ($project as $value) {
    $pg_address = $value['pg_address'];
    $pg_type = $value['pg_type'];
    $pg_owner = $value['pg_incharge_name'];
    $pg_mobile = $value['pg_incharge_mobile'];
    //print_r($pg_mobile);die;

?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#pgname" ).autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.php"
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name= "address" value="<?php echo @$value['pg_address']; ?>" required/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
    <label>PG Owner Name</label>
    <input class="border" type="text" name= "pg_owner" value="<?php echo @$value['pg_owner']; ?>" required/>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
 <div class="search">
   <label>PG Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="pgname" placeholder="Search by PG Name" name="pgname" list="locations" class="searchlocation" />  
   <button type="submit1" id ="submit1" class="searchButton">
     <i class="fa fa-search searchButtonSearch"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#pgname" ).autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php"
    });
});
</script>
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <label>Address</label>
  <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name= "address" value="<?php if(isset( $pg_address)) echo $pg_address; ?>" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
   <label>PG Owner Name</label>
   <input class="border" type="text" name= "pg_owner" value="<?php if(isset( $pg_owner) )echo $pg_owner; ?> required />
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi Hp_issei, i have tired your way not happening sir, i have inspected that html tag showing empty value only sir.

Comment: debug your `$row` value with `var_dump($row); die;`